# Why do symlinks in a duplicated folder turn into files after a few seconds?

Tags: finder, macos, symlink

I have a folder full of files. There are 98 images, and 98 symlinks to those images with alternate filenames.

When I hit Duplicate in the Finder on that folder, the copy succeeds normally. But in less than 30 seconds, *something* iterates over the symlinks and turns them into duplicate copies of the files.

- Only the copied folder is affected; the original folder is left untouched.
- The new duplicates are not hard links to the original files; the inode numbers are all different.
- The same behavior happens in both Finder and Path Finder.
- I can see the conversion happen in real time; it will go down the list changing them in small groups.

Can anyone duplicate this bug in Sierra or High Sierra?

---

- MacBookAir6,2
- macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the observed Finder/Path Finder behavior in a vanilla Sierra install. I'd expect it to be some tweak, a 3rd-party app or custom file & folder permissions.

To avoid the inconvenience use hard links in the source folder.